# How to make sure my timer run is race free

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is not the actual code, only to provide the idea behind the logic in actual code. Do I need a Mutex, mylock2 ,inside the timer function?. The timer runs every 0.02 seconds. Or, the timers are safe in that regard?.

```
Static NSTimer *mylock1 = nil;  //initialized and used for another purpose
Static NSTimer *mylock2 = nil   //initialized and used for the timer



- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    [mylock2  lock];
     Self.Mycount = 0;
     for (int j = 0; j <n; j++)
     {
         if (b) NSLog(@”Hi”);
          else Self.Mycount = Self.Mycount + 1;
     }
     If (Self.Mycount == n)
          [self stopMytimer];

    [mylock2  unlock];
}
```

Comment: NSTimer works with a run loop and isn't real-time, if that is what you are after.  A particular timer gets fired and/or rescheduled as needed when the run loop checks it.

Comment: the timer uses scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. if the timer gets fired every 0.02 sec, how to void overlapping timer calls?. is the lock as shown in the code indeed needed to prevent overlapping?. does "Self.Mycount" become 0 in middle of the for loop execution causing unexpected behaviors?. -thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might be misunderstanding how `NSTimer` works.

`NSTimer` invocation is handled by a run loop, when a timer is scheduled it is attached to the current run loop. A run loop is, unsurprisingly, a *loop* and runs on a single thread. Each iteration of the run loop a check is made if any timer needs to be fired, and if so it is *called* and so the next operation the run loop will do cannot occur until that call returns...

> the timer uses scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. if the timer gets fired every 0.02 sec, how to void overlapping timer calls?

Under normal circumstances calls simply cannot overlap as the next one cannot occur until the current one *returns*.

Of course if you dispatch work asynchronously to another thread within your timer, start another run loop from within the timer and schedule the timer on that one as well, or any other creative way you come up with then it is possible to create the conditions for "overlapping" calls. Your `timerFireMethod:` is doing nothing like that and will simply be called, execute, and return.

> does "Self.Mycount" become 0 in middle of the for loop execution causing unexpected behaviors?

Probably – as your method isn't designed for that scenario. But unless you fire up another thread (using NSThread, GCD (dispatch), etc.), and have it set `Mycount` to zero its not going to happen.

HTH